# Не удаётся записать файл во внешнее хранилище

Tags: android, kotlin, storage

Пытаюсь записать картинку во внешнюю память телефона (external storage), но папка и сам файл не создаются. На одном устройство всё работает, а на другом нет, пишет, что отказано в доступе. На котором работает, стоит версия sdk 25, а на другом 29.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/1588875980977.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

```
private fun checkPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 100)
        }
    }
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            settings.edit().putBoolean("save", true).apply()
        } else {
            settings.edit().putBoolean("save", false).apply()
        }
    }
}

private fun getImageUriFromBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap?): Uri{
    val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
    val file = File(path,System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".jpg")
    val output = FileOutputStream(file)
    bitmap!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output)
    output.flush()
    output.close()
    return Uri.fromFile(file)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116335/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-deprecated-in-api-level-29-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил данную проблему, добавив в манифест строку

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```